# What FET can I substitute for PF5102 or J305?

Tags: audio, microphone, fet, condenser-microphone

I want to build this microphone: https://www.instructables.com/id/Modify-a-cheap-LDC-Condenser-microphone

I am able to find all of the parts except for the FET. The schematic says to use PF5102, and the text of the instructable says that the author used J305. Neither of which are stocked by digikey, and from what I can tell they are not manufactured anymore.

I'm considering using J113, but I don't know enough about FETs to be confident that it would be a good substitute.

Here are the relevant datasheets:

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/PF5102-D.pdf

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MMBFJ305-D.pdf

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MMBFJ113-D.PDF

Comment: Welcome. Use many vendors for part searches. There are 4 or 5 of them.

Comment: Unfortunately shopping is off-topics for this site. But welcome.

Comment: @BrianCarlton Would it be better to ask something along the lines of what parameters are most important when trying to find a substitute JFET for an audio circuit? I felt like that was implied, but I guess I could have made it the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linear Systems](http://www.linearsystems.com/) and [InterFET](https://www.interfet.com/jfet-master-table/) still make the J305. Mouser has the [InterFET](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/676/jfet-j304-j305-interfet.r00-1649155.pdf) version in stock.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I just dismissed it when I saw it listed as "Obsolete" on digikey. It turns out that I found the best price on nightfire electronics, where the author of the instructable recommended getting it. I don't know why I didn't look there first.

Comment: JFETs are still the only way to do a few specialized instrumentation-related things, so I try to keep an eye on the changing landscape as they slowly get pushed out of most high-volume applications.